# Не выводится аргументы в системе регистраций

Tags: python, django

[image: Меню регистраций]

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Task_Models
from django.forms import ModelForm
    class RegisterForms(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'type': "text",
            'name': "name",
            'id': "name",
            'placeholder': "Имя пользователя",
        }),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                'type': "email",
                'name': "email",
                'id': "email",
                'placeholder': "e-mail"
            }),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'type': "password",
                'name': "pass1",
                'id': "pass1",
                'placeholder': "Пароль",
            }),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'type': "password",
                'name': "your_pass",
                'id': "your_pass",
                'placeholder': "Повторите пароль",
            })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для пароля попробуйте использовать это:

```
from django.forms import CharField, Form, PasswordInput

class UserForm(Form):
    password = CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password'}))
```

Проверил на `Django version 3.1.7` - работает и выводит плейсхолдер.